# How to check if number is within range of any number in array

Tags: arrays, math, p5.js

I am trying to create a short piece of code which takes an image, samples a random point on said image, and places a letter at that position before recording that position in an array. My problem is that the letters overlap too much and lowering the amount (because the position is random) creates very little density so is not viable. I am wanting to check my array of positions and see if the current position is within a certain (separate) x and y radius of any previous positions. How would I do that without looping through every number in the array (because the array gets rather large)

Here is my current code.

```
let x = floor(random(width));
let y = floor(random(height));
if(prev.includes(x+':'+y)!=true){
let col = img.get(x,y);
fill(red(col),green(col),blue(col));
text('E', x, y);
append(prev, x+':'+y);
```

As you can see, I append the position to the array in the x+':'+y format, and have it check if it is an exact copy of a previous one using the includes function. But I do not know how to do this for a radius.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are looking for something like this. This could be probably more optimized, but it works at least.

```js
var img;
var grid;
var elementSizeW = 10;
var elementSizeH = 10;

var arraySizeX, arraySizeY;
var totalElements;
var countElements = 0;

function setup()
{
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  
  img = loadImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Tabby_cat-yawning-03.jpg/800px-Tabby_cat-yawning-03.jpg');
  
  arraySizeX = floor(width / elementSizeW);
  arraySizeY = floor(height / elementSizeH);
  
  totalElements = arraySizeX * arraySizeY;
  
  // Create a grid, based on the size of the canvas
  // and the size of the text elements.
  // Element value is true when it's empty/free.
  grid = new Array(arraySizeY);
  
  for (let y = 0; y < arraySizeY; y++)
  {
    grid[y] = new Array(arraySizeX);
    
    for (let x = 0; x < arraySizeX; x++)
    {
      grid[y][x] = true;
    }
  }
}

function draw()
{
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    let x = floor(random(arraySizeX));
    let y = floor(random(arraySizeY));

    if (grid[y][x])
    {
      let index = (x + y * img.width) * 4;

      let colX = x / arraySizeX * img.width;
      let colY = y / arraySizeY * img.height;
      let col = img.get(colX, colY);

      let xPos = elementSizeW * 0.5 + x * elementSizeW;
      let yPos = elementSizeH * 0.5 + y * elementSizeH;

      fill(red(col), green(col), blue(col));
      text('#', xPos, yPos);

      grid[y][x] = false;

      countElements++;
    }

    if (countElements >= totalElements)
    {
      console.log("Done");
      noLoop();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```